# Syslog is flooded with PF_RING messages

Tags: logs

I have [ntop](https://www.ntop.org/) running on a Debian 9 (Stretch) server, and it's flooding `/var/log/syslog` with the following messages every 10 seconds:

```
Sep 21 11:51:18 brutus kernel: [67801.273760] [PF_RING] removing lo/info from /proc [net=18446626341580989120]
Sep 21 11:51:18 brutus kernel: [67801.273762] [PF_RING] removing lo from /proc [net=18446626341580989120]
Sep 21 11:51:18 brutus kernel: [67801.461801] [PF_RING] removing lo/info from /proc [net=18446626341682619200]
Sep 21 11:51:18 brutus kernel: [67801.461804] [PF_RING] removing lo from /proc [net=18446626341682619200]
Sep 21 11:51:18 brutus kernel: [67801.464365] [PF_RING] removing lo/info from /proc [net=18446626341794546432]
Sep 21 11:51:18 brutus kernel: [67801.464367] [PF_RING] removing lo from /proc [net=18446626341794546432]
Sep 21 11:51:18 brutus kernel: [67801.653773] [PF_RING] removing lo/info from /proc [net=18446626341794562944]
Sep 21 11:51:18 brutus kernel: [67801.653776] [PF_RING] removing lo from /proc [net=18446626341794562944]
Sep 21 11:51:28 brutus kernel: [67811.209792] [PF_RING] removing lo/info from /proc [net=18446626341580989376]
Sep 21 11:51:28 brutus kernel: [67811.209795] [PF_RING] removing lo from /proc [net=18446626341580989376]
Sep 21 11:51:28 brutus kernel: [67811.381941] [PF_RING] removing lo/info from /proc [net=18446626343937008704]
Sep 21 11:51:28 brutus kernel: [67811.381944] [PF_RING] removing lo from /proc [net=18446626343937008704]
Sep 21 11:51:28 brutus kernel: [67811.384587] [PF_RING] removing lo/info from /proc [net=18446626341791761408]
Sep 21 11:51:28 brutus kernel: [67811.384589] [PF_RING] removing lo from /proc [net=18446626341791761408]
Sep 21 11:51:28 brutus kernel: [67811.573931] [PF_RING] removing lo/info from /proc [net=18446626341783028864]
Sep 21 11:51:28 brutus kernel: [67811.573934] [PF_RING] removing lo from /proc [net=18446626341783028864]
```

1. What do these messages mean?
2. How can I reduce the amount of log messages? It's hard to find anything else amidst all of this.